# How to better manager memory when showing images in RecyclerView Android?

Tags: android, picasso, android-recyclerview

I am using `CardView` and `RecyclerView` to show list of cards, which is pretty heavy. In most of the cards is image which has `128dp` of height `match_parent` of width (so almost whole widht of screen).

I am loading this images with `Picasso` library.

The problem is that after some scrolling images no longer load, I think it is due to no memory left for images

> Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 45617(2MB) AllocSpace
>   objects, 8(256KB) LOS objects, 20% free, 7MB/9MB, paused 1.971ms total
>   116.640ms
>
> Suspending all threads took: 13.892ms

How can I make `RecyclerView` dump files which are not seen and load only new ones?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EventViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Event event = events.get(i);
    if (event.getThumbnail() != null) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(event.getThumbnail()).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
    } else {
        viewHolder.thumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
...
}
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_main_thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row_main_description"
    android:contentDescription="@string/event_picture"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

EDIT : 
I think the problem is not with the `RecyclerView` itself, but with the `else statement` I mean `setVisibility(View.GONE)` is messing here and that's why images are not appearing.

Comment: Load images only when user not scrolling!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EventViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Event event = events.get(i);
    if (event.getThumbnail() != null) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(event.getThumbnail()).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);
        viewHolder.thumbnail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.thumbnail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have just did the same. Weird how recycler view bind works.

Comment: @kodw : I don't think its weird if you see the principle of RecyclerView. ScrollView is a big paper where we have written down with a pen. Recylerview is like you have given a pencil and a eraser and one sheet of paper. Everytime the user scrolls, you need to erase the content and write it.